# Partial minimization over variable

Tags: optimization

Suppose that we have a general mathematical program $(P)$ with value
\begin{align}
\nu(P) := \min_{x,y}\; \{f(x,y) : g(x,y) \leq 0\}.
\end{align}
Is there a standard way to define functions $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$ so that we can write the problem in terms of $x$ only?
That is, can we always find $\tilde{f},\tilde{g}$ so that
\begin{align}
\nu(P) = \min_{x}\; \{\tilde{f}(x) : \tilde{g}(x) \leq 0\}
\end{align}
For example, when $g(x,y)=g(x)$, then
\begin{align}
\nu(P) = \min_{x}\; \{\tilde{f}(x) : g(x) \leq 0\}, \quad \tilde{f}(x) = \min_y f(x,y)
\end{align}
works.
My question is what happens when $y$ is involved in the constraint?

Comment: why do you think this is generally possible? In what context do you need this result?

Comment: I'm not sure that we can do this generally. I ask because in the LP setting, this amounts to projecting the problem onto $x$. I wonder if there is something similar in general.

Comment: In my case, I need this when $g$ is nonsmooth and nonconvex (e.g., something like $g(x,y) = \min(x,y) = 0$ that can be represented as an integer program) but $f$ is linear.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are looking to do? Perhaps a reformulation of some IP?

Comment: It is a network flow problem except for one additional constraint that is like $\min(x,y) = 0$. I take it that what I'm asking is only possible under very specific settings?

Comment: Let $\tilde{f}(x) = \min_y f(x,y)$, $\tilde{g}(x) = \max_y g(x,y)$. This doesn't really help, however.